# laravel json column change string to integer

Tags: laravel

I have json column in mysql table.
Now I want get items.

I have a problem here.
Reviews are stored as string like "1,300".

Because of this it does not work if I want to get items more than 500 reviews.

```
$items = Item::where('data->reviews', '>', 500)->get();
```

I think I need to change reviews to integer.

Any solution for this?

Comment: Did you store the review as string ?

Comment: Is there an error ? What do you mean of it does not work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need this type of query, then you need to rewrite and optimise your database logic and use relationship tables to handle this type of data. I don't think **JSON** column should be used here at all to store your reviews data.

But it is not like you cannot do it for this type of data. MySQL is capable enough to do it, but it is way too inefficient.

Here is a raw query, you will need to write a raw query for laravel too.

The where condition will be:

*NOTE: Use REPLACE() as per your need my test data had double quote " after first REPLACE. So the need of second REPLACE*

```
WHERE CAST(REPLACE(REPLACE(JSON_EXTRACT(data, '$.review'), ',',''), '"', '') AS DECIMAL) > 500
```

FULL RAW QUERY

```
SELECT * from items WHERE CAST(REPLACE(REPLACE(JSON_EXTRACT(data, '$.review'), ',',''), '"', '') AS DECIMAL) > 500
```

Laravel Eloquent Query :

```
Item::query()
     ->whereRaw("CAST(REPLACE(REPLACE(JSON_EXTRACT(data, '$.review'), ',',''), '\"', '') AS DECIMAL) > 500")
     ->get();
```

This does work but I will **not recommend** at all to use it.

Try to break that data to another table or column so you can have proper index and simplier query conditons.